# Regarding the UITabBarController, is there a way to force a view to be fully released when a new tab is selected

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, memory-management, uitabbarcontroller

I'm creating a tab bar application for the iPhone and I want whatever view is currently active to be fully unloaded/released if a new tab is selected. When any tab is reselected I want it to have to reload everything. The reason I seek this feature is because all views interact with a single database, and can modify the database. When the views are built they are built off the current database, which means that they can be out of date without a forced reload of the view.

To see what I'm referring to load the "Phone" app on your iPhone and you can type in a number on the keypad, switch tabs, switch back to the keypad and the number you typed remains there. Which is a desirable trait for the Phone app, but not so much for what I'm designing.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or, should I use another method to update my views when tabs are switched?

Comment: put reloading logics in `-(void)viewWillAppear`. You definitely do not need release the view.

Comment: How are you displaying the data? Are you using a table- or collection-view?

Comment: I totally forgot about asking this question; life went and got busy on me! Time to get my answers to these questions out. I tested it with the -(void)viewWillAppear method and will probably end up using that to reset the views when they are reactivated. I also am using this in conjunction with the -(void) viewWillDisappear function to handle view resets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Neil Galiaskarov comment that you should not think about releasing the view. His idea to put your current reloading logics in `-(void)viewWillAppear` is sound:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{ 
   [super viewWillAppeared:animated]; 
   // Any code you are currently triggering in your init / viewDidLoad 
   // to reload your database and display the result
}
```

This is triggered every time you return via the tab-bar and should give you the result you are after. There are few caveats however, depending on what you do next, that might not deliver the required functionality:

- The screen will be updated when it is reached by popping the stack (which is probably OK from what you are describing).
- If you start to navigate backwards in the stack with the swipe-gesture but abort the navigation the screen will also be updated. (As this triggers `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`).

If the latter is a problem one way to handle it through a `BOOL _shouldTriggerReload;`:

Wrap the `viewWillAppear` logic inside an if:

```
if (_shouldTriggerReload){
   _shouldTriggerReload = NO; // Preparing for the next round
   // Any code you are currently triggering in your init / viewDidLoad 
   // to reload your database and display the result
}
```

Then in your `viewDidDisappear`:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
   _shouldTriggerReload = YES;
}
```

And it will also have to be set inside your viewDidLoad for that first entry:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    _shouldTriggerReload = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

tabBarController has a `viewControllers` property.
You modify the viewControllers property to achieve such effect.

What i would do is,
For the `view controller(say VC)` which you want to reload its view, when user selects that tab.
add `UITabBarControllerDelegate` delegate to VC. and implement below method.

```
– tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:
```

when the user selects this in bottom tab bar, `tabBarController` calls this method whether should it show this viewController or not.
Here, `change the tabBarController.viewControllers` property and return YES.

Lets say your tab bar has only two viewControllers attached to it, and user now selects tab 2 and you have to create new viewController and show it.
So,

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController;
NSMutableArray *array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tabBarController.viewControllers];
UIViewController *viewController2; //init your viewController type 2
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:viewController2];
tabBarController.viewControllers =[NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
```

Comment: How this will cause reload of contents from database ?

Answer (score 0):

Use delegate method

`- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item`

Add your piece of code which you can trigger each time whenever you select tabBarItem.